# Vertical height of \longtable

Tags: longtable, height

How can I reduce vertical height of the \longtable. Note that all the document is double-spaced. I need the vertical spaces in the tables to be exactly adjusted as in the \tabular.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{ecltree}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}    
\usepackage{mathenv}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0cm}

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth}
\setlength\unitlength{0.5cm}


\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{ \scriptsize
\leftmark}} \rhead[\fancyplain{}{ \scriptsize
\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\setmarginsrb{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}{1cm}{1cm}{2cm}{0cm}
\makeindex % Composer l'index de fin de document.0

\bibliographystyle{authordate1} % Définit le style de la bibliographie
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth} \makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]
{\noindent\makebox[2em][r]{\@thefnmark.\,}#1} \makeatother
\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{
\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad} \makeatother
\renewcommand {\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}


\begin{document}
\scriptsize\begin{longtable}{lccc|ccc}  
%
\centering 
\caption{abc} \label{tab:result1}\\
\hline
%
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{2}}  \\%
VARIABLES & a & b & c & a & b & c  \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{7}{c}
%
{{\textbf{Table} \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}} \\
\hline \noalign{\vskip-3pt}
%
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{2}}  \\%
VARIABLES & a & b & c & a & b & c  \\
\hline
\endhead
%
\textit{Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
%
\hline
\endlastfoot

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.  This will also clarify if there are any issues that might be due to your preamble.

Comment: I don't know precisely the package or the commands for double spacing in the document, this is why I posted it all. Apologies for  making it long

Comment: Thanks, that certainly helps. But as it is, it does not compile for me due to an option clash.  Please fix that. But, also you really should make an attempt at reducing it. Keep removing packages and see if the problem still shows up, until you have removed most of them.

Comment: Irene, you use `\usepackage{setspace}` **and** `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}`. Delete the latter and use the `setspace` variant.

Comment: Thanks Peter, Maybe because it is a thesis code and the table I mention is inside a chapter. 
Speravir, Yes you are right, I tried \doublespacing instead of \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} but still the vertical spaces in the \longtable huge .

Answer (score 2):

The idea of making a MWE is that you remove all the packages that are not relevant, your MWE isn't at all minimal.

It also generates two errors

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.
```

and

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\caption ->\noalign
```

The latter is particular serious. `longtable` has no chance to generate correct spacing if given invalid input.

If you change your input to comment out the spurious lines

```
  %\usepackage[dvips]{color}
```

and

```
 %\centering
```

Then the document runs without error.

If the output is not as you wish you will need to clarify what you do want the output to be.

---

If you don't want the table double spaced you could use the cpmmands from teh setspace package or simply

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
```

before the table.